# Search through embedded collections in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, moloquent

I'm currently working on a PHP (laravel) project where we're using MongoDB (the jenssegers package). I made password resets up on the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d56135b462e816642abbd1"),
    "email" : "wesley@foo.bar",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-26T20:46:14.074Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-24T18:11:01.040Z"),
    "passwordReset" : [ 
        {
            "token" : "59b4b694e9ddcd9b44b0374eac595b28",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-24T18:11:05.017Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-24T18:11:05.017Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58d56139b462e816642abbd4")
        }
    ]
}
```

However, multiple users can have multiple `passwordReset`'s. So, when I want to search for tokens, I'd like to just be able to search through all resets instead of doing this:

```
    $users = User::all();
    $activeReset = null;
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (! is_null($user->passwordReset)) {
            foreach ($user->passwordReset as $reset) {
                if ($reset->token == $this->route('token')) {
                    $activeReset = $reset;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's a working solution, but it's not the prettiest, also, when the app goes into production, this will cause huge load times, which is not what I'm looking for.

However, just getting all resets through `PasswordReset::all();` results in an empty array.

So, is there a way to do this, without going through all users? Through `Laravel` itself or maybe through "raw" PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Please update the question with model relations definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all users who have at least 1 matching token, if you are using [EmbedsMany](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#embedsmany-relations) relation :

```
User::where('passwordReset', 'elemMatch', array('token' => $this->route('token')));
```

Comment: This returns null for me. Does it only work on EmbedsMany?

Comment: Yes, the query in the answer works with embedded documents, which was a fair assumption, based on the document structure in the question. If you are using another kind of relations, please update the question with relevant information. Questions like "*This returns null for me.*" also require [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).